# Python type hints: type hint a function in the middle of another function

Tags: python, type-hinting

Calling a function(func2) within func1, the return of func2 will go into variable.  Is this a correct way to type hint func2 that is within func1?  I should type hint the func2 call within func1?

```
def func1():  
   variable: Callable[[str, str], object] = func2(arg1, arg2)

def func2(arg1: str, arg2: str) -> object:
```

Comment: `variable` would be typed as `object`. What you did would be the case, if it was `variable: Callable[[str, str], object] = func2`.  `func2` wouldn't even be defined but im ignoring that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you're not assigning a function to `variable`, so it shouldn't be declared with a `Callable` type. You're assigning the *result*, which is `object`.

```
variable: object = func2(arg1, arg2)
```

You should use `Callable` if you're assigning the function itself, not calling it

```
variable: Callable[[str, str], object] = func2
```

Of course, in either of these cases, any type checker worth its salt is more than capable of inferring the types, so unless your function is unusually long and complicated, adding type annotations to local variables generally just adds noise without adding anything of value. And if your function *is* long enough to warrant it, you may consider refactoring before spamming annotations.

Personally, the only time I'll annotate a local variable is if its type is the result of a complicated generic function.

```
def complicated_thing(x: T, y: list[T]) -> dict[str, MyClass[T]]:
  ...

variable: dict[str, MyClass[int]] = complicated(foobar, [])
```

In this case, it may not be obvious, at a glance, what `T` is, so the annotation potentially adds something of value.